# use of http_query for sending a request to another server, kamailio script start fails

Tags: kamailio

Trying to authenticate the end user, for that need to query another server for the validation. So want to send the http get/post request from kamailio server to another server using http_query or similar methods.

But when use this function http_query() [got from http://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/4.0.x/modules/utils.html#idp25440 ], kamailio starts failing. Though not sure the real reason, looks like config file is not able to find the the function. So can you let me know which module or params need to load in config file so that error can be resolved.

Or any better way tosend simple http request and take decision based on the reply in kamailio.cfg file  and also what all module needs to be loaded to use those function?

Answer (score 1):

The **utils** module has to be loaded.

You have to look inside the syslog file (depending of the OS, it can be /var/log/syslog or /var/log/messages) and look for error messages printed by Kamailio. They should reveal the reasons it doesn't start.

If you don't manage locating syslog file for you OS, then redirect the debug messages printed by Kamailio to the terminal. Either set **log_stderror=yes** in kamailio.cfg or start kamailio by adding the **-E** command line parameter.

If you don't see any error messages from kamailio, then be sure you don't have the **utils** module loaded in between some #!ifdef ... #!endif statement that is not enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the update :)

verified the logs, seems utils lib file was not present.
compiled the util module separately, and place the llib in the searching path.
and now its working fine.